# Laravel Relationship with many to many model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am a beginner in laravel world and I face some difficulty in querying many to many relationships in laravel

This is my ERD:

[image: 1]

The airline field in the database is just temporary, which ideally I want to query from the airline table instead.

Is it possible to query like

```
$f = Trip::with('airline')->get();
echo $f->airline->first->name;
```

Trip.php

```
class Trip extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'capacity', 'fee', 'tour_id', 'flight_id', 'depart_time'
    ];

    public function flight()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Flight::class);
    }

    public function airline()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Airline::class, Flight::class);
    }
}
```

Flight.php

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'depart_time', 'arrive_time', 'fee', 'airline_id'
    ];

    public function trip()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Trip::class);
    }

    public function airline()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Airline::class);
    }
}
```

Airline.php

```
class Airline extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function flights()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Flight::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: well `$f` is a collection not a model but ... `$f->first()->airline->name` should be sufficient, assuming the relationship is correct

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'flights.trip_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `airlines`.*, `flights`.`trip_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `airlines` inner join `flights` on `flights`.`id` = `airlines`.`flight_id` where `flights`.`trip_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

i am getting this error ... i guess my relationship may have some problem

Answer (score 1):

for anyone that needs answer / solution...
I made a silly mistake to put same name (airline) in both function name in Flight.php and the field of Flight.. after i remove the airline property in the database, everything work just fine.